# Not able to store timestamp object to csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am trying to write max value of timestamp to csv and its not working.

```
max_time=status_rank['CREATED'].max()
max_time= pd.DataFrame(max_time)
max_time.to_csv('maxtime_prev_load.csv')
```

Its giving an error: Data-frame constructor not properly called

DataType

```
 type(max_time)
    pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

**Sample data**

```
max_time
Timestamp('2020-03-02 01:41:48')
```

How to fix this

Comment: You need to pass a `dict` I think like `pd.DataFrame({'Max Time': max_time})`

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx, Can you write as an answer. It will be helpful for other readers

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame` expects its input to be _ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame_, but you are providing a scalar, which is analogous to `pd.DataFrame(1)`.

Comment: @Chris, how can fix my issue then, I need to write `max value` to csv

Comment: Have you tried what @xxMrPHDxx suggested?

Comment: @Chris, It gives an error `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Comment: you can pass it as list `pd.DataFrame([max_time])`

Comment: @aeapen Enclose `max_time` in a `list` like `[max_time]` because `str` is iterable and it tries to treat one character as row as such `pd.DataFrame({'Max Time': [max_time]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this is using

```
    pd.DataFrame([max_time]) # or if you need add the column and index, you can try
    pd.DataFrame([max_time], index=['something you like'], columns=['something you like'])
```

Or following the answer provided by @xxMrPHDxx in the first comment(with small modification), you can do it by

```
    pd.DataFrame({'Max_time':[max_time]})
```

The important thing here is to add square brackets.